# Swift - NSHTTPCookie is nil

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

I am trying to write a couple cookies in Swift so that when I display a webview, it will be able to read those cookies and react appropriately. I found many examples of how to create the cookie and read the Apple docs but I can not seem to get a valid NSHTTPCookie object. It's always nil.

Here's my code:

```
let baseHost = "domain.com"
let oneYearInSeconds = NSTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)

func setCookie(key: String, value: AnyObject) {
    var cookieProps = [
        NSHTTPCookieOriginURL: baseHost,
        NSHTTPCookiePath: "/",
        NSHTTPCookieName: key,
        NSHTTPCookieValue: value,
        NSHTTPCookieSecure: "TRUE",
        NSHTTPCookieExpires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: oneYearInSeconds)
    ]

    var cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps)
    // This line fails due to the nil cookie
    NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie!)
}
```

My `cookie` variable is `nil`. I've tried many combinations of the properties including having both `NSHTTPCookieOriginURL` and `NSHTTPCookieDomain`, with and without `NSHTTPCookieSecure` and even without `NSHTTPCookieExpires`. Always `nil`.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you want to be using `NSHTTTPCookieDomain`, NOT `NSHTTPCookieOriginURL`.

Could you try the properties like so:

```
var cookieProps = [
        NSHTTPCookieDomain: baseHost,
        NSHTTPCookiePath: "/",
        NSHTTPCookieName: key,
        NSHTTPCookieValue: value,
        NSHTTPCookieSecure: "TRUE",
        NSHTTPCookieExpires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: oneYearInSeconds)
    ]
```

If you do not provide valid properties to the constructor, you will get a null value. You should be providing a boolean to `NSHTTPCookieSecure`, not a string.

Comment: Wow. I was SURE I tried that already but obviously I hadn't. That worked! I have to wait 8 minutes before I can accept your answer. I'll be back to do that later.

Comment: FYI, the source code for NSHTTPCookieSecure says it should be "TRUE" or "FALSE": 'A string stating whether the cookie should be transmitted only over secure channels. String value must be either "TRUE" or "FALSE". Default is "FALSE".'. I saw another location that said ANY value implied true.

Comment: I actually used `.domain` which gave me nil, but changed it to `.originURL` and now it works ‍♂️